# What's the required to make a normal user can create schema on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I created a new database `test` and created user 'eonil' with this command:

```
CREATE ROLE eonil LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password' NOINHERIT VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
```

on my PostgreSQL.
I run `psql -U eonil test`.
When I tried to make a new schema, it shows an error.

```
test=> CREATE SCHEMA new_schema AUTHORIZATION eonil;
ERROR:  permission denied for database test
test=>
```

Why does this make an error? What's required?

Answer (score 30):

Grant the user `CREATE` privilege on the database, e.g.

```
GRANT CREATE ON DATABASE test TO eonil
```

The `CREATE` privilege, when applied to an existing database, enables the User to create a new schema within the database.  The official documentation for what other access privileges you can `GRANT` is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html).